# What is the right architecture\design to perform javascript-client to aws-database website tracking system

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-sdk, event-tracking

We wish to build data pipeline system which tracks website interactions/events.
The goal is to track user behavior in a website so we would like to choose the right architecture to implement it having the following two constraints :
1) the system is Amazon 
2) this is budgetary project so we cannot use redshift for this purpose

Based on the above two constraints my plan is to implement the following architecture:

**website-javascript --> AWS-S3 -->(AWS-Lambda)--> AWS-RDS**

**website javascript client** - 
aws-firehose data delivery system to S3 -  tracking user interaction and load them to aws-firehose which eventually write them in aws-S3.

**AWS Lambda (Python)** - Periodically task which pulls daily events from AWS-S3 and load them to AWS-RDS.

The reason I have chosen AWS-RDS is due to its cost-effectiveness for this objective

Appreciate any comment to the above mentioned implementation or any other architecture proposal that you may recommend to use instead of the above

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) _"if your question generally covers… a specific programming problem (**no**), or a software algorithm (**no**), or software tools commonly used by programmers (**maybe**); and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development (**no**)"_

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you are proposing below solution to perform web analytics for your application:

**WebServer --> Firehose --> AWS-S3 --> AWS-Lambda --> AWS-RDS**

I see below pros and cons with above design

Pros:

1. low cost
2. easy to implement

Cons:

1. RDS may not be salable enough to handle analytics on massive amounts of web-streaming data, which tend to grow rapidly
2. Need to handle load balancing, failure scenarios and other complexities for lambda
3. You need to handle data transformation for RDS as it expects structured data to be ingested into relational tables

Proposal to store the data in S3 through Firehose sounds a good solution. But please keep in mind that minimum interval for Firehose is one minute, so your application needs to tolerate this minor latency. You may use Kinesis Streams to have millisecond latency, but then you need to manage your own application code and instances to handle Streams.

After ingesting data in Kinesis Firehose or Streams, you may also explore below alternatives:

- Use Kinesis Analytics to track web users activity in real-time if it's available in your AWS region. It's only available in selected AWS regions currently
- Within Firehose, transform your data using lambda and store it in S3 in optimized format for further analysis with AWS Athena
- Use Elastic Search as a destination and perform web analytics with ELK stack instead of RDS
- Though you mentioned that you can not use RedShift, it still may be the best solution for time series analysis. Exploring RedShift, RedShift Spectrum and formatted data stored in S3 may still be a cost effective solution with better cababilities

Adding few references from AWS, which you may go through before deciding on the solution:

[Real-Time Web Analytics with Kinesis Data Analytics Solution](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/introducing-the-real-time-web-analytics-with-kinesis-data-analytics-solution/)

[Near Real-time Analytics on Streaming Data with Amazon Kinesis and Amazon Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/perform-near-real-time-analytics-on-streaming-data-with-amazon-kinesis-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service/)

[Schema-On-Read Analytics Pipeline Using Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-schema-on-read-analytics-pipeline-using-amazon-athena/)

[Amazon Redshift Spectrum Extends Data Warehousing Out to Exabytes—No Loading Required](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-spectrum-extends-data-warehousing-out-to-exabytes-no-loading-required/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey folky this is a getting more and more common.

Generally the pattern is click events to Kinesis streams then you can monitor user interaction with the website in real time using Kinesis analytics. You can connect the stream to firehose to offload data in to an S3 bucket as well as incorporate Lambdas to transform the data.

There is some major complexity around handling Lambdas and Kinesis streams in parallel so this solution might not be as scalable as using AWS Kafka. Or perhaps run a job to move your s3 data into rds for whatever reporting you might need that is adhoc.

Here is a pattern AWS already has [real-time-web-analytics-with-kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/real-time-web-analytics-with-kinesis/)